# GitLab - department-based permissions (groups etc.)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ee

I'm new as a Junior IT Administrator and I'm wondering where to start. I've been assigned a task by the IT manager, which I need to complete.

The task involves creating a directory structure/project groups on gitlab.noname.com, where access to individual directories will be granted based on user assignment to the appropriate department, for example, NameGroup1, NameGroup2, etc.

I also want to check if this can be done at the group level in AD. It seems to me that it's possible. I searched Google and found the following information:

1. https://medal.ctb.upm.es/internal/gitlab/help/administration/auth/ldap-ee.md
2. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/ldap_synchronization.html?tab=Docker

So far, I've created two new groups in our local AD, namely:

`!NameGroup1 !NameGroup2`

I've also created 2 groups on the gitlab.noname.com portal (NameGroup1, NameGroup2) and will continue from there.

My question is, should I enter the following in **gitlab-rails.rb**:

```
main:
label: 'LDAP'
.....
admin_group: '!GitlabAdmins'
groups:
- 'CN=!NameGroup1,CN=Users,DC=noname,DC=en'
- 'CN=!NameGroup2,CN=Users,DC=noname,DC=en'
```

or

```
main:
label: 'LDAP'
.....
admin_group: '!GitlabAdmins'
groups:
- !NameGroup1
- !NameGroup2
```

I'm not sure, please help.

Comment: The first one should work: GitLab requires the full distinguished names (DNs) of the AD groups to correctly bind and synchronize the groups between AD and GitLab.